# RHEL Desktop Recorders... Do they exist?

Tags: desktop, redhat-enterprise-linux, recording

I've been searching a lot for a desktop recoder on RHEL 6 lately (for tutorial videos about how to use RHEL desktop for non-linux users)

But unfortunately, I didn't find anything... Just some desktop recorder for Ubuntu, none for Fedora or CentOS. (Maybe I wasn't looking where I should have...)

So there is my question, do you know any good desktop recorders for Linux?

These are my RHEL version informations:

- RHEL 6.1
- x86_64
- Kernel : 2.6.32-131.4.1.el6.x86_64

ps : If my RHEL configuration info is lacking, ask me, and I'll provide them as quick as I can. Solutions mentioned in [Screen capturing application for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/943/screen-capturing-application-for-linux)  do not work in x86_64.

Comment: All the solution on the possible duplicate don't work for RHEL x86_64. Already tried them.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions which ask for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly and attract subjective answers. For advice on how to ask a question which may require recommending software, see [this Meta Super User post](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/).

Comment: . . . 5 years later, that's quite the usefull comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that Istanbul does in fact work on Red Hat-based Linux distributions. It may not have yet been updated for RHEL 6, but you can try building from source. The Fedora Wiki has [**an entire article**](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/ScreenCasting) with instructions on setting the software up for screencasting.

Another alternative to record operating systems that do not have recording software is to install it in a virtual machine and record from the host operating system. This also allows you to have a smaller workspace to record, allowing for smaller resolution videos.

Comment: Thanks you. I was thinking that Istanbul wasn't working because I use a x64_86, but now that I think about it I think it's more because of RHEL 6.

I'll try this out today and tell if it work.